# Trouble updating a resource

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongoose

I'm trying to update a transaction, but instead its updating that one and at the same time deleting the other ones. My focus is to just update one transaction. Can someone check my backend logic please.

My Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

mongoose.Schema.Types.String.set('trim', true)

const transactionSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    note: { type: String, required: true },
    amount: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: true,
      ref: 'User',
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
)

const WalletSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true,
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: [true, 'Please enter a name'],
  },
  balance: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
  },
  transactions: [transactionSchema],
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Wallet', WalletSchema)
```

My backend controller logic:

```
exports.updateWalletTransactions = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const { amount, note } = req.body
  const foundWallet = await Wallet.findOne({ user: req.user.id })

  foundWallet.transactions = foundWallet.transactions.filter(
    (trans) => trans._id.toString() === req.params.id
  )

  if (foundWallet.transactions) {
    foundWallet.transactions[0].amount =
      amount || foundWallet.transactions[0].amount
    foundWallet.transactions[0].note = note || foundWallet.transactions[0]
    const updatedTransaction = await foundWallet.save()
    return res.status(200).json(updatedTransaction)
  } else {
    return next(new ErrorResponse('Transaction not found', 404))
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method of Array that will only return the specified transaction.

the better approach is to write your code using the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method like this:

```
exports.updateWalletTransactions = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const { amount, note } = req.body;
  const foundWallet = await Wallet.findOne({ user: req.user.id });

  if (!foundWallet) return next(new ErrorResponse("no wallet found", 404));

  const transIndex = foundWallet.transactions.findIndex(
    (trans) => trans._id.toString() === req.params.id
  );

  if (!transIndex) return next(new ErrorResponse("Transaction not found", 404));

  foundWallet.transactions = foundWallet.transactions.map((trans) => {
    if (trans._id.toString() === req.params.id) {
      trans.amount = amount || trans.amount;
      trans.note = note || trans.note;
    }
    return trans;
  });

  const updatedWallet = await foundWallet.save();
  const updatedTransactions = updatedWallet.transactions;
  return res.status(200).json(updatedTransactions);
});
```

or you can do it like this:

```
exports.updateWalletTransactions = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const { amount, note } = req.body;
  const foundWallet = await Wallet.findOne({ user: req.user.id });

  if (!foundWallet) return next(new ErrorResponse("no wallet found", 404));

  const transIndex = foundWallet.transactions.findIndex(
    (trans) => trans._id.toString() === req.params.id
  );
  
  const trans = foundWallet.transactions[transIndex];
  
  if (trans) {
    trans.amount = amount || trans.amount;
    trans.note = note || trans.note;
  } else {
    return next(new ErrorResponse("Transaction not found", 404));
  }

  const updatedWallet = await foundWallet.save();
  const updatedTransactions = updatedWallet.transactions;
  return res.status(200).json(updatedTransactions);
});
```

Comment: No offense but using forEach is kinda obsolete and the best practice is using array methods which will give you cleaner and more concise code. by the way in my second approach you don't have to use if checks on each array element so it's faster and more performant.

Comment: Both were great solutions, I appreciate them both. I picked first one because of the checks. I will give your code a try, and update the best answer If I am pleased.

Comment: Like you say, yours is better for performance and cleaner. I chose yours. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the transaction. Better to iterate over each transaction and update on matching transaction id.

```
exports.updateWalletTransactions = asyncHandler(async(req, res, next) => {
  const {
    amount,
    note
  } = req.body;
  const foundWallet = await Wallet.findOne({
    user: req.user.id
  })
  let transFound = false;
  if (foundWallet) {
    foundWallet.transactions.forEach(trans => {
      if (trans._id.toString() === req.params.id) {
        transFound = true;
        trans.amount = amount || trans.amount
        trans.note = note || trans.note
      }
    })
    if(transFound){
      const updatedTransaction = await foundWallet.save()
      return res.status(200).json(updatedTransaction)
    } else {
      return next(new ErrorResponse('Transaction not found', 404))
    }
  } else {
    return next(new ErrorResponse('User Id not found', 404))
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you, I like both approaches.

Comment: welcome.. please do not forget to accept the answer

Comment: Sorry dude, the other answer was better for performance. Your answer worked too!

Comment: i agree with you :)